# Как получить выбранное пользователем значение во время сохранения экземпляра модели Django

Tags: python, django

Есть вот такое поле модели:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    categories =models.ManyToManyField(
        Category,
        related_name='products')
```

Я хочу переопределить метод save для Product. Для этого мне нужно получить во время сохранения значения поля categories, которые выбрал пользователь. Что я делаю:

```
def save(self):
    super().save() #сохраняю объект как обычно
    parents = self.categories.all() #затем пытаюсь получить то, что сохранилось в нужном мне поле
```

но в parents записывается старое значение, а не то, которое выбрал пользователеь. Хотя после сохранения поле изменяется. Что я делаю не так?

UPD. Пока жду ответа, почитал про сигналы, но даже с ними получается та же самая ерунда. Во-первых, вынес функцию отдельно, а не в сейв:

```
def primer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    parents = instance.categories.all()
    print(parents)
```

Во-вторых, добавил сигнал:

```
models.signals.post_save.connect(primer, sender=Product)
```

Функция срабатывает и выводит в консоль принт. Но в выводе содержится значение, которое было ДО сохранения. Теперь я еще больше не понимаю что происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ сам. Действительно, для этой задачи надо использовать сигналы. Но вот только сигнал post_save не подходит, т.к. Джанго обрабатывает ManyToManyFields уже после вызова этого сигнала. Поэтому существует специальный сигнал m2m_changed специально для этих целей:

```
models.signals.m2m_changed.connect(primer, sender=Product.categories.through)
```

[Документация по этому поводу](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed%23m2m-changed)